# Google cloud function sending command to IoT device

Tags: google-cloud-functions, mqtt

I am trying to write a function that will send command to a device defined in Google Cloud IoT core. Sending a command from the console works fine.

I’m using the following example from [Sending commands to devices](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/commands#api)

```
// const cloudRegion = 'us-central1';
// const deviceId = 'my-device';
// const commandMessage = 'message for device';
// const projectId = 'adjective-noun-123';
// const registryId = 'my-registry';
const iot = require('@google-cloud/iot');
const iotClient = new iot.v1.DeviceManagerClient({
  // optional auth parameters.
});

const formattedName = iotClient.devicePath(
  projectId,
  cloudRegion,
  registryId,
  deviceId
);
const binaryData = Buffer.from(commandMessage);
const request = {
  name: formattedName,
  binaryData: binaryData,
};

try {
  const responses = await iotClient.sendCommandToDevice(request);

  console.log('Sent command: ', responses[0]);
} catch (err) {
  console.error('Could not send command:', err);
}
```

However, in my function log I get the message‘Error: Node.js v10.0.0 is a minimum requirement.‘

I have run node -v in my project and I get v10.16.3 as a result so I am confused. Can anyone offer any advice?

gcloud functions describe results :

```
availableMemoryMb: 256
entryPoint: updateDevice
eventTrigger:
  eventType: providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create
  failurePolicy: {}
  resource: projects/project/databases/(default)/documents/pubsubMessages/{docID}
  service: firestore.googleapis.com
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-firebase
name: projects/project/locations/us-central1/functions/updateDevice
runtime: nodejs8
serviceAccountEmail: email@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-xxx
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2020-05-18T09:56:29.144Z'
versionId: '46'
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/iot": "^2.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^1.7.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^7.14.4",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "google-auth-library": "^6.0.0",
    "googleapis": "^51.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Can you post the output of gcloud functions describe so that we may see how your function is defined?

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/describe

Comment: Show us the package.json

Comment: Having run gcloud functions describe i see that runtime: nodejs8 and in the package.json, I see "engines": { "node": "8"}. Does this mean that I can't do what I;m trying to do in a firebase function or can this be updated to v10? Thanks for your help. Although I have been a developer for many years, Google cloud and node.js is all a bit new to me as I'm just trying to learn something while being furloughed.

Comment: Why arent you using nodejs10 for cloud functions?

Comment: Hsn - very good question. I've only recently ventured into the Google cloud stuff since I've been furloughed and went with the default. Previous replies showed me the error of my ways and I have spent the morning updating. Thanks all for your help.